# Bootstrap 3 form force full width block labels

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create Bootstrap form and force "mobile like" view on all screen widths.
In other words I would like my labels to be above the fields, not left of them.
This is part of my form:

```
<form action="thanks.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textarea">Where?</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" class="form-control "></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is the default form layout in BS3, but your markup is much more complex than it needs to be.  Something like this should get you what you are asking for:

```
<form action="thanks.php" method="post" role="form">
    <fieldset>
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textarea">Where?</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="textarea" class="form-control "></textarea>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[Bootply](http://bootply.com/99683)

Answer (score 1):

Simply force the label into a block element:

```
<label for="textarea">Where?</label>
<div>
    <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" class="form-control "></textarea>
</div>

label { display:block; }
```

You didn't post your CSS so its hard to tell if you are doing that yet or not.

For mobile I usually force form elements to width:97% as well.

Comment: I didn't post my CSS, since it is standard bootstrap 3 CSS: http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css
and label {display:block} won't work. There should be some class in Bootstrap that will force layout to do this.